# Trying to trim 500 columns that has many needing dummy variables-R

Tags: r

I've got a data set with 500 columns and many of them will require dummy variables to avoid linearity (ie: income levels that add up to 100%).  I'm trying to develop a regression model. I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid manually going through the columns and adding dummies?  Any thoughts would be appreciated.  I'm trying to determine the 20 or so variables that are significant.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use caret::dummyVars

Comment: Thanks-I will give this a try